# Varnish VCL Configuration for Multisite Drupal?

Tags: drupal, varnish, varnish-vcl, drupal-multi-domain

My current setup is:

- Varnish at `:80` and Drupal at `:8080` are on same box
- Drupal is running as Multisites, such as, `site1.xx.com`, `site2.xx.com`
- Multisite Domains are settled by Apache V.Hosts

Is there any Standard/Common VCL Configuration using on such kind of Drupal Setup? OR, the Default VCL file will mean it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the cookie domain in settings.php and use [this guide](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/varnish-multiple-web-servers-drupal) to add drupal.vcl for your version of the Varnish.